# Search Files in AWS S3 by LastModified

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I want to search files in AWS S3 based on file creation time (or LastModified)  time in go. I am aware of same in python using boto3 paginator which provides the options to provide the query string but want to achieve same in go.

Any suggestion or any sample in go-lang would be appreciated?

Sample code I am trying to list all files:

```
for s.NextContinuationToken != ""  { 

        maxFileRead := 15

        bucket := "XXX-XXX-test"

        // To check if previous result  was truncated
        if s.IsTruncated {
            fileList, err = s.session.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
                Bucket:            aws.String(bucket),
                MaxKeys:           aws.Int64(maxFileRead),
                ContinuationToken: &s.NextContinuationToken,
            })
        } else {
            fileList, err = s.session.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
                Bucket:      aws.String(bucket),
                MaxKeys:     aws.Int64(maxFileRead),
            })
        }

        s.IsTruncated = *fileList.IsTruncated

        if s.IsTruncated {
            s.NextContinuationToken = *fileList.NextContinuationToken
        } else {
            s.NextContinuationToken = ""
        }

        if err != nil {
            if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
                switch aerr.Code() {
                case s3.ErrCodeNoSuchBucket:
                    fmt.Println(s3.ErrCodeNoSuchBucket, aerr.Error())
                default:
                    fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
                }
            } else {
                // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
                // Message from an error.
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
            }
    }
}
```

Now I want to  modify the  search to only list files created after a particular time.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show what you've tried and what issue you've had? Requests for 3rd party resources/tutorials/etc are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Adrian modified the above code  with sample code.

Comment: @user3445024 Show your attempt at filtering by last modified and any problems that you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call ListObjectsV2 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjectsV2) on each bucket.
2. The Contents property returned is a list of metadata about each bucket object.
3. Use the LastModified field.